# Convert UTC to EST by taking care of daylight saving

Tags: php, datetime

I want to convert UTC time to EST by taking care to daylight saving in PHP.
This is what i did so far:

```
$from='UTC';
$to='EST';
$format='Y-m-d H:i:s';
$date=date('2106-03-15 23:00:00');// UTC time
date_default_timezone_set($from);
$newDatetime = strtotime($date);
date_default_timezone_set($to);
$newDatetime = date($format, $newDatetime);
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo $newDatetime ;//EST time
```

It's returning `6:00 AM EST`,but due to daylight saving It should be `7:00AM EST`

Any Idea?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think there are two faults here. One is that specifying Eastern **Standard** Time seems to mean daylight saving is ignored. The other is that you've typed 2106 when I think you meant 2016 and daylight saving time won't have started on 15 March 2106. The following appears to work:

```
$from='UTC';
$to='America/New_York';
$format='Y-m-d H:i:s';
$date=date('2016-03-15 23:00:00');// UTC time
date_default_timezone_set($from);
$newDatetime = strtotime($date);
date_default_timezone_set($to);
$newDatetime = date($format, $newDatetime);
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo $newDatetime ;//EST time
```

On the other hand using the `DateTime` class is a bit easier to read, and this is very similar to the first example in the documentation for [`DateTime::setTimeZone()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php)

```
$date = new DateTime('2016-03-15 23:00:00', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: I used the second example, and converted a date with time 1:01AM from UTC to EDT (which should be 9:01PM), but its showing 8:01PM, maybe it does not account for daylight savings?

Comment: I get 9:01pm.
php > $date = new DateTime('2016-03-15 01:01:00', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
php > $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
php > echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
2016-03-14 21:01:00

Comment: Yeah this works, I was doing this in bulk and misread the data, Thanks for confirming.