# How convert from timestamp from SQL data to EST timezone

Tags: php

As you can see
'. date('M-d-Y h:i:s A', strtotime($row['email_open_datetime'])) .'

I would like to make simple convert from timestamp to EST time zone. Right now, i belive timestamp based on UTC from SQL server. I did look all over place and couldn't find what Im looking for. Please help! :(

```
if($total_row > 0) {
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $status = '';
        if($row['email_status'] == 'yes') {
            $status = '<span class="label label-success">Open</span>';
        }else{
            $status = '<span class="label label-danger">Not Open</span>';
        }
        $output .= '
            <tr>
             <td>'.$row["email_address"].'</td>
             <td>'.$row["email_subject"].'</td>
             <td>'.$status.'</td>
             <td>'. date('M-d-Y h:i:s A', strtotime($row['email_open_datetime'])) .'</td>

            </tr>';
    }
} else {
    $output .= '
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" align="center">No Email Send Data Found</td>
        </tr>';
}
```

Comment: What is the current value of `$row['email_open_datetime']` (say for a particular db record) ?

Comment: From SQL. It is output showed "Mar-02-2022 08:02:48 PM"

right now it is my est time show 10:02:48PM. I would like convert from "Mar-02-2022 08:02:48 PM" to my est time zone.

Comment: Here is the answer you looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/36012664/9154326

Comment: If you speak the Eastern Standard Time Zone (EST) then your time information in the comment is not correct. EST: UTC−05:00.